# cache / save to dB google Static Images on request

Tags: google-maps

We run a real estate portal, and heavily use mapping.

We also utilise static images served from google. My question is this, because of the number of requests we are making to the google servers, we do not wish to become blacklisted.

Sooo .. is there a way, that when we generate a static map image we can save a copy to our dB.

The static map images are requested dynamically, based on search within our site..

Example., user searches for Bondi Beach, NSW our geo location software, sends that request to Google, to retrieve the map image, for the address which has been converted to its lat and long.

I wasnt sure if there was a way, or simultaneously, storing that NEW request as an image file, within the dB somehow. Then when a secondary request etc is made for the same location, the image is retrieved from our dB and files, and if this fails, loads in from Google, because placename match is incorrect etc.

Any help appreciated.

Ste

Comment: You are not allowed to save google map images to database. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html Section 10.1.3.

Comment: Yeah read that, but it also states: except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of “places.”