# Caching Static Google Maps server side

Tags: google-maps

I'm using Google API for Work and has .Net available as backend (though any language is fine for logic).

Current implementation 
I've a dropdown where user selects a city and Google Maps JavaScript widget alongside displays presence locations for a company in that city. If there are 10 cities, all users will always see the same visual on map for each city. However, if they zoom or move map, then its specific to the user. When user changes the dropdown. I know the latitude and longitude of all locations and are in database.

Question:

1. When user changes a city, I noticed there are lot of requests made to map API by widget, most of which download portions of map image and some download scripts. Are all requests counted for billing OR the there's some specific request which counts to a usage hit?
2. Since Google allows limited caching (but not pre-fetching), I want to cache the first request made by end user for each city  (so if there are 10 cities, 10 keys) for a day. If user does zoom/move, that won't be cached. But how to achieve initial cached rendering as there are so many requests that JavaScript widget makes and where in maps widget do I hook server caching?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to care about these requests, they don't affect any limit. The only affected limit will be the map-load(1  per each load of the maps-API, usually you load the API once per page).

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle for this. 1. stands resolved. However, I'd still like to cache that first map load for a day after it is hit first due to big traffix causing huge $. Is that possible? Based on https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#server it makes sense in my case and is recommended.

Comment: Which kind of request you want to cache, when you've stored the LatLng's for all cities in your DB there is nothing to request.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7100747/12484